# How to define the blank value of a field from shapefile to raster file based on GDAL_Rasterize？

Tags: gdal

I have tens of shapefiles and want to convert to raster based on CT field(as Fig.1).
However,CT fields of some polygons is blank,and these value is set to 0 when I use following gdal_rasterize code. I had assumed that -a_nodata parameter is set nodata is -2,but the output file has no -2.

My question is how to set the blank of CT value to a fixed value(for example -2) when using GDAL_Rasterize?

```
gdal_rasterize -a CT -l cis_SGRDREA_20160104T1800Z_pl_a -a_nodata -2 -init -1 cis_SGRDREA_20160104T1800Z_pl_a.shp G:\CIS_Sea_Ice_Chart_3573\2016\EA_Raster/cis_SGRDREA_20160104T1800Z_pl_a_CT.tif -tr 1000 1000 -ot Int16
```

[image]

```
                                        Fig.1
```

Comment: Perhaps it is due to `-init -1` which may not make sense together with -a_nodata. But shapefiles do not really have null values in fields and I guess it would be better to update you data first: CT empty -> -2.

Comment: Oh,sorry.I have tried it as you said to remove `-init -1` ,however those area is still 0.

Comment: It seems that CT field is actually a string field. That string "01" gets converted into number "1" is probably exactly what you want but the situation may be better under your control if you create a new integer field for gdal_rasterize.

Comment: Yeah,you are right. I've noticed that the parameter is string.I created a new integer field for gdal_rasterize .My encountered problem is that '00' is present in CT field and those blank in attribute fields are converted to 0 simultaneously, however, I don't want the blank field become same(00) as '00' polygons' CT field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dbf format that is used for storing attributes in shapefile does not support null values. The values that look empty in the CT field may actually have zeroes in the dbf file. See "Data type containing null value" in http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geoprocessing_considerations_for_shapefile_output. I would suggest to update the value of CT for example into "-2" to represent unknown/missing data.

Comment: Yeah,dbf format file contains the attributes of different polygons,but I opened the dbf file to find the CT field of those areas are indeed blank rather than zeros.

Comment: They may just look blank because your software has some logic to handle them as blanks. Another software, in this case GDAL, may not use the same logic. Anyway nulls in dbf files are fuzzy. If you just want to get your job done go ahead and update the data and you should be fine. If you are very interested in this, study the dbf records with a hex editor and read http://dbfviewer.com/dbf-file-structure/